# Entity Framework (Core) Query Multiple Tables From 2 Different Databases

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I write a query to get data from 2 (or more) tables from different databases with EF Core? I have now the following code:

```
var items = (
    from o in _db1.Orders
    join c in _db2.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
    where c.CustomerId = 1
    select c;
).ToList();
```

In MySql I have this query that needs to be transformed to the expression above (`Linq`).

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM db1.Customers c
   JOIN db2.Orders o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId 
WHERE c.CustomerId = 1;
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is not supported as of today and there are no plans to support it

This and other related features are mentioned at the end of [this EF Core issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4898)

Comment: I'm using `FromSql` for now which works fine for now, but I don't want to use SQL strings